# Is lease allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, quran, hadith, money

Would you please clarify if purchasing goods on rentals are allowed in Islam?

According to what we studied, a fixed percentage of interest is added to the principal amount (current price) of that product to calculate the rental payments (which is received from lessee) for each month's payment.

That's, in lease income schedule prepared by lessor (who gives goods on rentals) includes separate columns for calculation of

1. Principal amount (actual price of product).
2. Interest.
3. Rental Income (actual amount + interest).

Comment: Can you please separate the second sentence into several parts? As it stands, it's too long and complex to grasp the intended meaning.

Comment: I tried my best to simplify my question as much as I can.. Hopefully u can understand my words now

Comment: try to add the tags "practical islam" "money" "hadith" "quran" to attract more quality answers.

Answer (score -4):

No, lease is not allowed in Islam. so the person who took it for lease should pay some amount every month so that it will not lead to haram

Comment: please explain your answer?